# Exclude results if all this words are matched from SQlite3 query in PHP

Tags: php, sqlite

I want to do a SQLITE3 QUERY that allows to me to exclude results that matches a specific amount of words. For example.

SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE TEXT NOT LIKE ("ONE","TWO", "THREE");

I want to exclude results only if all this words are matches. But if only "ONE" and "TWO" are matched, then do not exclude that. Also, if only one word is matched, do not exclude.

I would prefer to do it with the LIKE statement

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can try using `INSTR` as follows:

```
SELECT *
FROM yourTable
WHERE
    INSTR(text, 'ONE') = 0 OR
    INSTR(text, 'TWO') = 0 OR
    INSTR(text, 'THREE') = 0;
```

This logic returns a record if *any* one of `ONE`, `TWO`, or `THREE` be missing in the text.

Here is the case insensitive version:

```
SELECT *
FROM yourTable
WHERE
    INSTR(UPPER(text), 'ONE') = 0 OR
    INSTR(UPPER(text), 'TWO') = 0 OR
    INSTR(UPPER(text), 'THREE') = 0;
```

Comment: Is there any way that I might make this INSTR case insensitive?

Comment: Yes, simply uppercase the column before comparing to `ONE`, `TWO`, and `THREE`.